# how to read incoming sms in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to read an sms and get a verification code and authenticate automatically.

I found this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_receiver) and tried its sample code. It doesn't seem to be working. Any other way I can do this? Or maybe I'm using it wrong. Here's the code:

```
  String _verificationCode;
  SmsReceiver _smsReceiver;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
    _smsReceiver = SmsReceiver(onSmsReceived);
  }

  void onSmsReceived(String message) =>
      setState(() => _verificationCode = message.split(" ").elementAt(2));

  void _startListening() => _smsReceiver.startListening();
.
.
.
} else if (url.toLowerCase().contains('verify')) {
                if (_verificationCode == null) {
                  _startListening();
                }
```

This is almost the same code in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same issue with flutter packages, for listening to incoming messages, but nothing worked for me.

So I created a BroadCastReceiver in android and with the help of [Custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab) I connect this with flutter.

BroadCastReceiver

```
   public class MyMsgReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if(SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals
       ("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
         for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent))
           {
               msg = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
               user = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            }
          }
        }
     };
```

Add this reciever to manifest file(app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".MyMsgReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Add permission to app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Hope this method help someone!!!

Comment: Nice workaround. I did manage to make the existing packages work, I don't remember how though. If anyone finds this thread and wants the solution, ping me and I will dig up my old repos.

Comment: hey @Divya, I need more help with this

Comment: @Eren, I need help with this

Answer (score -2):

Using this package: [flutter_sms](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms)

Then create an SMS Receiver instance.

```
SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();

receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg)
    if(sender == "56789"){
       textEditorController.text = msg.message;
}    
);
```

Comment: SmsReceiver is from the package I shared rather than yours. Am I getting something wrong? @DARSH

Comment: not able to get the SmsReciever in the current package.